# Serialization of Javascript from Server(NodeJS) to Browser

Tags: javascript, serialization, node.js

I would like to serialize an instance of JS object from the Server-side to the Client side
(the object contains data members and functions)

I have a Javascript stack on both end, all my users use Chrome and My server side is a NodeJS impl..

how would I do it? It should be trivial as my server is a Javascript one..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could send it as JSON string. [Here's an example](http://www.mattfreeman.co.uk/2010/03/nodejs-json-data-services-javascript-web-scraping-fu/):

```
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
response.write(JSON.stringify(yourObject));
response.close();
```

Comment: Have you tried Ajax? Note that client side javascript knows nothing about server side language. So traditional techniques should be used on the client side.

Comment: of course I would use AJAX, but I do I convert the String to an Object?

Comment: Well, there's `eval` but if you use a javascript framework such as jQuery it will automatically give you a js object in the AJAX `success` callback. For example: `$.post('/foo', function(obj) { /** obj will be directly an object here **/ });`

Comment: the JSON object also offers a parse method, so JSON.parse(str) is a safer alternative to eval.  However it is not supported on some older versions of browsers, so you'd want to include the http://www.json.org/json2.js library on the client side if you need to support ie7 etc.